# Display only “completed” items on account page Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I have customised the "My Account" area of Woocommerce to have a custom page on the side menu entitled "Collections".

The following shortcode displays all orders on the page

```
    function shortcode_my_orders( $atts ) {
        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'order_count' => -1
        ), $atts ) );

        ob_start();
        wc_get_template( 'myaccount/my-orders.php', array(
            'current_user'  => get_user_by( 'id', get_current_user_id() ),
            'order_count'   => $order_count
        ) );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

add_shortcode('my_orders', 'shortcode_my_orders');
```

I then added this filter to only display completed orders:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'custom_my_orders_query' );
function custom_my_orders_query($args){
    $args['post_status'] = array('wc-completed');
    return $args;
}
```

But this displayed completed orders not only on the 'collection' page but also the general orders page.... So I tried to add a if statement so collections would display completed orders but the order page would show everything but this is not working - just seems to ignore and just display all orders again :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'custom_my_orders_query' );
function custom_my_orders_query($args){
    if ( is_page('collection') ) $args['post_status'] = array('wc-completed');
    return $args;
}
```

The page is called collection but it doesnt work - help!

Thank you,
Jason

Answer (score 0):

Using This :

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
        'post_status' => 'wc-completed', 
        'numberposts' => -1,
        // for current user id
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => $user_id,
    );

    // Get all customer orders
    $customer_orders = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Thank you for this - where does this go? Do I keep the filter?

Comment: Filter may not required

Comment: I have removed the filter so it is just the shortcode and the array you goave me and it has gone back to showing all orders.

Comment: Thank you for your time - do you have any further suggestions?